# Unable to Install Entando 5 from maven artifact

Tags: failed-installation, entando

I try to install Entando as describe in the documentation http://docs.entando.com/#installation using the maven archetype
    mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=entando-archetype-webapp-generic

the option to install version 5 is never shown.

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=entando-archetype-webapp-generic
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: remote -> org.entando.entando:entando-archetype-webapp-generic (Generic web app Archetype for Entando: an agile, modern and user-centric open source web app like platform.)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 1
Choose org.entando.entando:entando-archetype-webapp-generic version: 
1: 4.3.2
2: 4.3.3
Choose a number: 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

The maven central archetype catalog is only updated on Sundays. Since this release was on a Tuesday it won't show up until the following Sunday which was June 4th. It should be a choice now

Alternatively you can add this XML to your archetype-catalog.xml in your .m2/repository directory.

```
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-bundle-content</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>Content Type Bundle Archetype for Entando.</description>
</archetype>
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-bundle-theme-generic</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>Theme (Page Model) Bundle Archetype for Entando.</description>
</archetype>
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-bundle-widget-generic</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>Widget Bundle Archetype for Entando.</description>
</archetype>
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-plugin-generic</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>Plugin Archetype for Entando:  an agile, modern and user-centric open source web app like platform.</description>
</archetype>
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-entando-sample</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>Entando sample web app Archetype: an agile, modern and user-centric open source web app like platform.</description>
</archetype>
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-webapp-generic</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>Generic web app Archetype for Entando: an agile, modern and user-centric open source web app like platform.</description>
</archetype>
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
  <artifactId>entando-archetype-web-app-BPM</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <description>RedHat BPM web application Archetype for Entando: an agile, modern and user-centric open source web app like.</description>
</archetype>
```